# weyl group element and subtorus

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a Lie group G, let $\alpha_i$ be one of its character elements. Then we can define a subtorus of maximal torus $T$ of codimension 1 by $T_{\alpha_{i}}=(ker\alpha_{i})^{\circ}$. Here we identify a weyl group element $s_{j}$ as an element in $N(T)/T$ corresponding to a different root from $\alpha_{i}$. Is it true that for any $t\in T_{\alpha_{i}}$, there exists a $t'\in T_{\alpha_{i}}$ such that $ts_{j}=s_{j}t'$?

This is true for the Lie group of type $A$. For the general case, it's not so obvious that this is true. If this is not true in general, are there some counterexamples?

I will appreciate any comments or answer.

Comment: In the first sentence I assume you already choose a maximal torus $T$ and let $\alpha_i$ be one of its characters. But I don't understand the sentence "Here we identify a weyl group element ..." More precisely, I know how to identify the Weyl group with $N(T)/T$, but the remainder of the sentence is unclear: Do you mean you choose $s_j$ as a reflection at some root different from $\alpha_i$ (which means it's not an arbitrary element of the Weyl group)?

Comment: Yes, first we identify weyl group with $N(T)/T$, and think of $s_{i}$ as an element in $N(T)/T$. Indeed, It means $s_{\alpha_{j}}$ where $\alpha_{j}$ is different from \alpha_{i}.

Comment: But then for $t, t' \in T_{\alpha_i} \subset T$, what is $ts_j$ resp. $s_j t'$ supposed to mean, if $s_j \in N(T)/T$? Wouldn't you need to choose a lift of $s_j$ to $N(T)$ to make non-trivial statements here?

Comment: Yes, I meant the lift of $s_{j}$.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" lift. You mean for an arbitrary but fixed lift?

Comment: Let me put it in another way. Let $s_{j}$ be one of the representative element in $N(T)/T$ so that $s_{j}$ is an element in $G$.

Comment: Ok. Well how do you prove it for type A?

Comment: I find it a bit hard to believe because unless I'm mistaken, you're asking whether $s_j^{-1}T_{\alpha_i} s_j = T_{\alpha_i}$. But isn't the very definition of the Weyl group action that $\alpha_i(s_j^{-1} t s_j) = s_j(\alpha_i)(t)$, hence $s_j^{-1}T_{\alpha_i} s_j = T_{s_j(\alpha_i)}$? But then take e.g. $s_j(\alpha_i) = \alpha_i + \alpha_j$ (which occurs in all $A_{n \ge 2}$): Is not $T_{\alpha_i} \neq T_{\alpha_i + \alpha_j}$?

Comment: Indeed you are correct. I just realize that this is not true in general. Thank you for your clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn comments into an answer: This result is not true in general.

Namely, what you are asking is whether:
$$s_j^{-1}T_{\alpha_i}s_j \stackrel{?}=T_{\alpha_i}$$
 But the Weyl group action on the roots is defined via
$$\alpha_i(s_j^{-1}ts_j)=s_j(\alpha_i)(t)$$
and consequently we have:
$$s_j^{-1} T_{\alpha_i}s_j =T_{s_j(\alpha_i)}$$

Now I'm relatively sure that as soon as $s_j(\alpha_i) \neq \pm \alpha_i$, we have $T_{\alpha_i} \neq T_{s_j(\alpha_i)}$, and such a pair of $s_j$ and $\alpha_i$ occurs in every root system except those that consist (thanks @Moishe Kohan) only of a sum of copies of $A_1$.

Comment: Right. More precisely, such $s_j$ exist as long as $W$ is nonabelian, i.e. when the root system is not a direct sum of $A_1$'s.